# Linguist not ignoring all files in various sub and sub-sub directories

Tags: github, gitattributes, github-linguist

I am trying to overwrite linguist with a `.gitattributes` file to not recognize ANY `.tex` document.

I have a bunch of `.tex` files contained in various parts of a file tree within a sub directory. So a file tree looks like this

```
|
|-- src/
|   |-- _extensions/
|   |   |-- andrewheiss/
|   |   |   |-- hikmah/
|   |   |   |   |-- partials/
|   |   |   |   |   |-- before-body.tex
|   |   |   |   |   |-- title.tex
|   |   |   |   |-- styles/
|   |   |   |   |   |-- pretty.scss
|   |   |   |   |-- _extension.yml
|   |   |   |   |-- include-in-header.tex
|   |   |   |-- hikmah-manuscript/
|   |   |   |   |-- partials/
|   |   |   |   |   |-- before-body.tex
|   |   |   |   |   |-- title.tex
|   |   |   |   |-- styles/
|   |   |   |   |   |-- pretty.scss
|   |   |   |   |-- _extension.yml
|   |   |   |   |-- include-in-header.tex
|   |-- main-analysis.qmd
|   |-- R/
|   |   | regex-function.R
|-- out/
|   |-- main-analysis.pdf
|-- .gitattributes
|-- .gitignore
|-- renv/
```

How would I get linguist to ignore all of the files in the `_extensions` directory?

I have already tried things like:

```
src/_extensions/** language-vendored
src/**/.tex -language-vendored
```

and have had no luck.

Any advice?

Comment: The first line should work (the second revert). Can you share the link to the repository?